# Why delete someone's answer after they improved it based on suggestions?

Tags: discussion

If a person is asking a question and someone is trying to answer it, but there are some suggestions to improve the answer based on which the answer is improved, why would the answer be deleted?

The person who has asked the question has no knowledge of this, will it not be unfair? At least the person asking the question can check if answer is helping him or not, but why delete the answer itself?

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: Yes. [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666511/debugging-web-workers-in-safari-web-inspector/40584469#40584469)

Comment: Hmmm ... to me, it seems you did what was asked (10k users can see deleted answers). We'll have to wait for a ♦ moderator to explain.

Comment: Looks like your post was targeted [by a bot](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/126814?m=34031491#34031491).  Users look at this and then flag the post.  A moderator responded by deleting it.  Can't say I'm too thrilled about these practices, too often an answer is targeted instead of the question.  But that's the way it rolls these days.

Comment: @HansPassant: only humans flagged the post.

Comment: Yes, that's what I implied: "users look at this".

Comment: @HansPassant: right, but it doesn't matter how the humans found the post. There is a *lot* of content on SO, using tools to help filter that flood is fine in my book.

Comment: @HansPassant: and us moderators get actual bot flags *all the time*, then look at those. How is that specific bot any different from that?

Comment: There are a lot of *questions* on SO.  Filtering that flood is fine in my book.

Answer (score 9):

I deleted your [your answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666511/debugging-web-workers-in-safari-web-inspector/40584469#40584469) based on the initial revision, I had missed the later edit (I was on a train and missed the 'post has been updated' notification).

*However*, do note that you failed to address the question even with the edit. The question states:

> I see the worker script loaded and I put a break point on it, but it doesn't break.

and your answer is

> Have you tried using debugger?

with a little exposition on using `debugger` in a piece of code. As it stands, this is asking for clarification and not an actual answer, it is merely a question. To be an answer, you'd have to expand on this. Something along the lines of:

> I believe you need to use the `debugger` statement; insert it into the code you are trying to debug and Safari will stop the code there. This is different from adding a breakpoint in the developer tools.

I've undeleted it, as it could be you meant for your question to be read rhetorically. However, a good answer would have *tried out the suggestion* to show that it works.

Comment: Debugger which i have suggested is different way of putting break point (in a code itself not from web inspector) which might help him

Comment: @ChromeApp: yes, I understand that it is different. However, did you actually determine if it works? If not, then your answer is not helpful. It doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @ChromeApp: if you didn't know if it would work, then you are basically asking them a question; *Did you try this and did it work?*. That's better left to comments, not to answers. Since you don't have the reputation to comment, the question is better left alone and your energy would be better spent on questions you do know the answer to.